# Creating a rectangle? - Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, type-mismatch, algebraic-data-types

```
rectangleRaster :: Coord -> Coord -> Raster
rectangleRaster a b = (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
```

Rectangle is defined by two points:

```
data Shape
    = Point Point
    | Rectangle Point
                Point
    | Circle Point
            Point
    | Line Point
        Point
    | Polygon [Point]
    deriving (Show)
```

and Point is defined as

```
type Point = (Double, Double)
```

where:

```
type Shade = Double
type Coord = (Int, Int)
```

and

```
type Pixel = (Coord, Shade)
type Raster = [Pixel]
```

error:

```
src\View.hs:70:24: error:
* Couldn't match type `Shape' with `[Pixel]'
  Expected type: Raster
    Actual type: Shape
* In the expression: (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
  In an equation for `rectangleRaster':
      rectangleRaster a b = (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
   |
70 | rectangleRaster a b = (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src\View.hs:70:34: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[(Coord, Integer)]' with `(Double, Double)'
      Expected type: Point
        Actual type: [(Coord, Integer)]
    * In the first argument of `Rectangle', namely `[(a, 1)]'
      In the expression: (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
      In an equation for `rectangleRaster':
          rectangleRaster a b = (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
   |
70 | rectangleRaster a b = (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^

src\View.hs:70:43: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[(Coord, Integer)]' with `(Double, Double)'
      Expected type: Point
        Actual type: [(Coord, Integer)]
    * In the second argument of `Rectangle', namely `[(b, 1)]'
      In the expression: (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
      In an equation for `rectangleRaster':
          rectangleRaster a b = (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
   |
70 | rectangleRaster a b = (Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)])
   |
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? It might have something to do with Raster being a list of [Pixel], if so, can anyone help me fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You don't seem to quite understand the difference between `type` and `data`. `Raster`, `Shade` and `Coord` don't exist anywhere but at the type level, where they're just aliases for existing types

Comment: Yeah I realised that when I made the post. I've edited the post to what I've attempted and still getting an error. Sorry I'm new to Haskell and I make silly mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do, but if you want to write a function with the type given for `rectangleRaster`, you don't have to involve `Rectangle`.

The simplest solution that looks like the OP is something like this:

```
rectangleRaster :: Coord -> Coord -> Raster
rectangleRaster a b = [(a, 1), (b, 1)]
```

Here, I've hard-coded the `Shade` value of each `Pixel` as `1`, as that looks like the attempted solution in the OP.

You can call the function like this:

```
*Q50128894> rectangleRaster (1,2) (3,4)
[((1,2),1.0),((3,4),1.0)]
```

If, on the other hand, you want to create a `Rectangle`, you'll need to supply two `Point` values, which you can do like in the following GHCi example:

```
*Q50128894> Rectangle (1,2) (3,4)
Rectangle (1.0,2.0) (3.0,4.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Rectangle` is a data constructor. It creates a value of type `Shape`, according to the definition

```
data Shape = .... | Rectangle Point Point | ....
--   ^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^
--   type           data      type  type
--                constructor
```

It in fact has type `Rectangle :: Point -> Point -> Shape`.

But in your definition

```
rectangleRaster :: Coord -> Coord -> Raster
rectangleRaster a b = Rectangle [(a, 1)] [(b, 1)]
```

you have proclaimed `rectangleRaster` as a function returning `Raster`, not `Shape`. Hence the type mismatch error. Which even says,

```
src\View.hs:70:24: error:
* Couldn't match type `Shape' with `[Pixel]'
  Expected type: Raster
    Actual type: Shape
```

i.e. it *expects* to find `Raster`, as per your declaration / type specification, but it *actually* finds a value of type `Shape`, being constructed by the data constructor `Rectangle :: Point -> Point -> Shape`.